# Facebook App Analytics Push Campaigns using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, facebook-analytics

I am trying to integrate Facebook app analytics push campaign into android/iOS app.
We have already got a custom push mechanism using Firebase Messaging.

Going through the the set up steps to  set up push campaings (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/push-campaigns/android)
I see that it requires app to use GCM.

Is it possible to configure Facebook app analytics push campaign & in app notification features using Firebase Messaging ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FCM for Facebook app analytics push campaign. Enter the same Server Key of your App(FCM Console -> Project Settings) to Facebook Analytics Settings Page under API Key.

Follow the same instructions for App,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/push-campaigns/android

You can also test if the push notifications delivers fine in Facebook Analytics page Event Debug section.

For Inapp Notification you have to add  the following to your gradle dependencies:

compile 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1.+'

https://github.com/facebook/FBNotifications

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. In fact, you need Firebase Cloud Messaging in order to configure Facebook Push Notifications. If you see the content of the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/push-notifications/quickstart, notice how under the heading "In-App Notifications", it says: "Prior to sending in-app notifications you will also need to integrate the FBNotifications library." Then if you go to https://github.com/facebook/FBNotifications, you will see that under the heading "Getting Started on Android", it says: "After you've added the dependency, you'll have to set up an FCM listener service,..." It is asking you to set up an FCM listener service and providing this link which contains the instructions to configure Firebase Cloud Messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client.

Conclusion: Firebase Cloud Messaging is not an option if you want to configure Facebook Analytics Push Campaigns. It is required. Firebase Cloud Messaging can operate without Facebook Analytics Push Campaigns, but not vice versa.